# is it possible to export .mdx and .mdl files?

Tags: export, file-format

is it possible to export to `.mdl` or `.mdx` files?
If yes, tell me the exact way please. Me and my friend are working on a Warcraft map, but Warcraft only imports `.mdx` or `.mdl` files and blender can't export this kind of files.

Comment: A simple google search comes up with results.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Blender-MDL](https://github.com/CruzR/Blender-MDL) addon.

It is also listed in official import/export extension section of the documentation at [wiki.blender.org](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/WarCraft_MDL)

Comment: Just a note to say that the addon has to be enabled in Blender (menu File->User Preferences->Addons->Import/Export).